# How often can Intimidating Glare be used?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, barbarian

The Intimidating Glare Barbarian Power does not note that there is a restriction about how often you can use the ability. As far as I understood, rage powers can only be used while in rage, but if the intimidating glare can be used multiple times during a rage (for a move action each), it's a pretty powerful ability.

Can someone clarify how often per rage this ability can be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see any restrictions on how frequently you can use it, but note that:

> You can attempt to intimidate an opponent again, but each additional check increases the DC by +5. This increase resets after one hour has passed.

So, Intimidating Glare basically changes the normal Demoralize action by:

- Decreasing the action cost from a standard to a move action.
- Reducing the range from 30 feet to just adjacency.
- Increasing the base duration from 1 round to 1d4.

This is clearly an improvement, but I don't see it as crazily powerful or anything. [Cornugon Smash](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cornugon-smash-combat) is substantially better in most cases (though you can't get it until later).

Comment: "One hour has passed." Starting when? Between two glares? Or after the first one?

Comment: @Eregrith after the last one, I'd say.

Comment: @Eregith, I read it as +5 for each other attempt in the past hour.

Answer (score 1):

The [table of rage powers](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers) in the SRD lists some powers as being "once per rage".

There is no such restriction against Intimidating Glare.